# How to update draft grade from Google Classroom using api in php

Tags: php, oauth, google-api-php-client, google-api-client, google-classroom

I am trying to updates draft grades from the dashboard created using Google Classroom API to the Google classroom itself for a project. I wrote the following codes but can't find the way out. How to solve this problem?

A dashboard(all values imported from Google classroom) is attached for your reference.

```
 $client = new Google_Client();
        $service = new \Google_Service_Classroom($client);
        $courseId = '328776504166';
        $courseWorkId = '361223650991';
        $id = 'Cg0IiOu99CkQr_3t1MEK';
        $post_body = new \Google_Service_Classroom_StudentSubmission(array(
            'updateMask' => 20,
            'draftGrade' => 90,

        ));
        $list = $service->courses_courseWork_studentSubmissions->patch($courseId, $courseWorkId, $id, $post_body,);
```

Then when I run the above code on localhost I see this problem:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "@ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is not permitted to make this request.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "@ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is not permitted to make this request.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

[Dashboard created using Google classroom api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKJ2l.png)

Comment: Whats the issue with your current solution, do you have an error?

Comment: @DaImTo  Yes I see something wrong . I've updated my question. The above problems appear when I want to update the draft grade.

Comment: @DaImTo I have to create the course, course work(assignment) from my project. Thank you so much for giving valuable suggestions.  Now this problem is fully fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that your call has not been authorized. Some methoes like [courses.courseWork/create](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/create) access private user data. In order to access private user data your application must be authorized by the owner of that data and have access granted to you.

i recommend following the [quick start](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/php) it will show you how to authorize your app.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Classroom API PHP Quickstart');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Classroom::CLASSROOM_COURSES_READONLY);
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
```

Comment: I've updated my error. Now The above problems PERMISSION_DENIED appear whenever  I want to update the draft grade.

Comment: I have to create the course, course work(assignment) from my project . Thank you so much for giving valuable suggestions.  Now this problem is fully fixed.

Comment: Please remember to accept the anwser if it helped you